# My csrf token is not getting created

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I have the following spring configuration

```
<http pattern="/signin" security="none" />

<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <csrf />
   .....
</http>

<beans:bean name="requestDataValueProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor"/>
```

In my sigin page i have the following as described in spring CSRF documentation

```
     <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

But i see both values are empty. I have no clue why it is empty or did i missed any configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have security "none" on the signin page.

Remove the line:

```
<http pattern="/signin" security="none" />
```

Instead insert inside your other `http`:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="permitAll" />
```